# Isn't this question too broad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, too-broad

The following question: [How do I attract new programmers?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/54/40) has been closed as **Too Broad** and then reopened.

I argue that it is far broader than [How do I structure my project in an inviting way?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/10/40) which has been closed as too broad.

Comment: The second question you linked is on its way to be reopened at 3/5.

Comment: Relevant: this all happened within the span of half an hour.

Comment: @Mast We're in the first day of private beta. half an hour is like 10 days in our little expanding universe.

Comment: I posted a link as a comment in my question asking for more people to weigh in. I admit I'm a little biased since it's my question, but advice is always welcome (even if it ends up being closed again).

Answer (score 8):

I voted to close both questions as Too Broad. For *How do I attract new programmers?*, here's my reasoning:

- The question isn't clear: Once it's built, how do I get other programmers to want to contribute? Not only would this be considered opinion based, but many will argue that there are a million ways to do this. It's just like asking, how can I go to school? You can walk, bike, bus... You get the point.
- Also, it doesn't provide many details as in what kind of programmers, or any information that one could normally expect.

For the second question, *How do I structure my project in an inviting way?*, here's why I closed it:

- The question is also broad, in that there is a million different answers: organize, make it pretty with colours! It's not specific.

For those who are casting reopen votes, I can't speak for them, but I hope to hear their reasoning as well. As for this, this is why I cast close votes.

Answer (score 3):

I'd just like to address an implication, which may or may not apply in this case: it's possible for a question to be too broad, but a superset question to not be too broad.

Car analogy:

Q: What do I do when my car is low on gas? A: Go to a gas station and refill it.

Q: Which gas station should I go to? A: too broad

The first question includes the second one, but it addresses a higher-level problem, whose set of possible solutions is quite limited.

The first question you linked could be understood as a superset of the second linked question - "structuring my project in an inviting way" is a possible solution to "How do I attract new programmers", but the first doesn't go into how, the second does.

Comment: I see your point, but the analogy doesn't do it for me. :/ I disagree though. I feel that these questions will be broad no matter what. Instead, they should be asking things like can such [feature] help me attract programmers?